# EXC_BAD_ACCESS trying to use skpsmtpmessage

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, email

I'm trying to use the skpsmtpmessage library to send email from my iPad program. All goes well through SMTP authentication and occasionally even successfully sends an email. However, I always get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS in exactly the same point:

```
libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend:
0x140708c:  movl   8(%esp), %ecx
0x1407090:  movl   4(%esp), %eax
0x1407094:  testl  %eax, %eax
0x1407096:  je     0x14070e8                 ; objc_msgSend + 92
0x1407098:  movl   (%eax), %edx
0x140709a:  pushl  %edi
0x140709b:  movl   8(%edx), %edi                 <Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xe0000008
0x140709e:  pushl  %esi
```

Comment: You have a bad pointer...have you enabled zombie objects?

Comment: I just switched to [mailcore](http://libmailcore.com). That did the trick.